# R append two data.frames when data are factors

Tags: r

I have two data frames that I wish to append into one as one single column of labels; but rbind is not working as expected, probably because the data are factors:

```
> str(trainLabels)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 ...
> head(trainLabels)
[1] 1 0 0 1 0 1
Levels: 0 1

> str(testLabels)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
> head(testLabels)
[1] 1 0 1 0 0 0
Levels: 0 1

trainPlusTestLabels <- rbind(trainLabels, testLabels)
```

Then:

```
head(trainPlusTestLabels)
```

gives me a strange output. trainPlusTestLabels does not have the structure I wish to have.

```
> str(trainPlusTestLabels)
 int [1:2, 1:9000] 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "trainLabels" "testLabels"
  ..$ : NULL
```

How can I append the two sets of labels to have just one column of labels?

Comment: It *looks* to me like "trainLabels" and "testLabels" are `vector`s, not `data.frame`s. `rbind` would do something quite different in that case.

Comment: You'd want to use `c()` to combine 2 vectors.

Comment: ...or `data.frame(train = trainLabels,test = testLabels)` if you want them as columns in a data frame.

Comment: @tcash21, if using `c()` they'd have to convert to `character` first. Better to use `unlist(list(trainLabels, testLables), use.names = FALSE)`.

Comment: @tcash21 c() gives me values like 2, when the labels should only be "0" or "1".

Comment: You can convert to numeric by using `as.numeric` and do `rbind`. It should work

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thanks. Looks like this is working: trainPlusTestLabels <- unlist(list(trainLabels, testLabels), use.names = FALSE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of problems I see:

1. The `str` you post indicates that you are not dealing with `data.frame`s, but `vector`s. When you use `rbind` on `vector`s you'll get a `matrix` as the result (which is what you see in your "trainPlusTestLabels" `str`).
2. Converting `factor`s directly in a matrix like that just grabs the underlying numeric value (1 and 2), so you would have to do some `as.numeric(as.character(...))` to get the desired output.

Alternatively, you can use `unlist` on a `list` of your vectors. Try:

```
unlist(list(trainLabels, testLabels), use.names = FALSE)
```

Note that this still results in a `vector`, not a `data.frame` :-)

Comment: One can also use `as.vector()` because there is an `as.vector.factor` which method that applies the `as.numeric(as.character(.))` in the "correct" DWIM fashion.

Comment: @DWin, not sure I follow. Are you saying something like `c(as.vector(trainLabels), as.vector(testLabels))`? That works but gives me a character vector as the output.

Comment: Wasn't a character vector what was needed?

Comment: @DWin, I thought a `factor` vector was needed, which you would get with the `unlist...` approach in my answer.

Comment: Huh. That was a bit of a surprise to me. I now understand your point about `rbind.data.frame` as well. Kids at home, Ananda is really onto something important here.